# Use/convert Linux shell command "echo 1=200 > /dev/mydevice" into c programm

Tags: c, shell, linux-device-driver

I'd like to use following Shell command in my c programm:

```
echo 1=150 > /dev/mydevice
```

If I'm right the syntax for echo is:

```
echo [option(s)] [string(s)]
```

So I came up with the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int fd = open("/dev/mydevice", O_RDWR);
    write(fd, "1=150", 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it even possible that way? Can you spot out the error(s)?

Is there a good option do debug a device write?

---

EDIT:

Thanks a million!!!

It was the Newline caracter. Now I was able to work out two solutions:

1)

```
 int main()
    {
        int fd = open("/dev/mydevice", O_RDWR);
        write(fd, "1=150\n", 6);
        return 0;
    }
```

2)

```
int main()
{
    system("echo 1=150 > /dev/mydevice");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `echo` command as written would also produce a newline, which your C program does not output. (It outputs a null terminator instead.) Otherwise, it seems fine, apart from omitting the part that closes the file descriptor, and omitting the error checking.

Comment: You can directly use system calling `system("echo 1=150 > /dev/mydevice")`

Comment: assuming the device knows what to do with the char string, it would be much faster (and much more informative) to just run your code rather than asking us.

Comment: @R.S.NikhilKrishna: Directly using the file I/O facilities is much better than using `system` here. Using `system` just means you have to go through the expense of one or more process launches that take several orders of magnitude longer than the nanoseconds to low microseconds worth of work involved, and ultimately do the same work themselves.

Comment: Please post the solution you found as a proper answer, not inside the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missed the "Answer-Button". I already put the answer as an edit to the question.